# Stop thread after finishing executing a certain task

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I have written some code which stops a thread when a "STOP" button is pressed. It works, with some caveats. It tends to freeze up resources for a second or two and it stops everything as soon as it is pressed. I would like for the stop button to stop the thread once it is finished what it is doing.

Here is the function I have created for the stop event:

```
def Stop(self, event):
    if myClass.worker != None:
        if myClass.browser!=None:
            while(myClass.browser.quit()!=None):
                myClass.browser.quit()
        myClass.worker.stop()
        myClass.worker = None
        while True:
            try:
                myfile = open(self.fpath, "r+")
                myfile.close()
                break
            except IOError:
                myClass.closeIt(self)
        os.unlink(self.fpath)
        os.rename(self.temp, self.fpath)
```

Basically if no thread is spawned (hence it is not None), it quits a browser window and then stops the thread which is scraping information from a webpage on the browser. It then saves the file it is writing to.

The thread that is actually stopped is an instance of the openExcel class I have created:

```
myClass.worker = openExcel(temp)
```

Instances of this class call a function called findDomains:

```
def findDomains(self,searchrow, numrows, sheet, wbook):
    for i in range(searchrow, numrows):
        domain = sheet.cell_value(i, 2)

        if domain == "":
            company = sheet.cell_value(i, 1)
            self.browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 300)
            inputGoogle=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q")))
            inputGoogle.clear()
            inputGoogle.send_keys(company)
            inputGoogle.submit()

            self.browser.refresh()
            tries = 0
            while tries<1000:
                try:
                    domain=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cite._Rm")))
                    domain = domain.text
                    break
                except StaleElementReferenceException:
                    tries+=1
                    self.browser.refresh()

            domainlength=len(domain)
            period=0
            for charac in range(domainlength):
                if domain[charac]==".":
                    period+=1
            if period==1:
                if "//" in domain:
                    domain = domain.split("//",1)[1]
                index = domain.find("/")
                domain = domain[:index]
            elif period > 1:
                domain = domain.split(".",1)[1]
                index = domain.find("/")
                domain = domain[:index]

            checkdom=domain.split(".",1)[0]

            if (checkdom+".") not in domain:
                domain="error"

            worksheet.write(i,2,domain)
            wbook.save(file)
```

Instead of stopping everything it is doing in this function, I'd like for the stop feature to wait until the "domain" is saved to the excel sheet. I.E. for it to finish what it is doing, before trying to close a browser and quit.

Comment: hi, can you try doing a MCSE that replicates the issue you're having by replacing most of the non relevant part of your code with mockups? That exercise might actually help you discover what's wrong with it!

Comment: a [minimal complete simple example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Actually it's an MCVE... Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example :)

Comment: @zmo Here is all the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/43a2e85c0ed9439ff60c its not really possible to condense the code.